# How to generate multi dimensional list in python

Tags: python, arrays

I try to generate a multi dimensional list depending on two variables: `size` and `dim`. Both of them are initialized with user input, so I don't know their values while coding. An example with `dim = 3` and `size = 2` would be: `[[['+', '+'], ['+', '+']], [['+', '+'], ['+', '+']]]`. What I have tried so far:

```
import copy
fields = '+'
for i in range(dim):
    fields = [copy.copy(fields) for j in range(size)]
```

While this works totally fine for `dim in [1, 2]`, it only creates references to the same list if `dim > 2`. Example with `size = 3` and `dim = 3`:

```
>>> f
[[['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']], [['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']], [['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']]]
>>> f[0][0][0] = 'X'
>>> f
[[['X', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']], [['X', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']], [['X', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+'], ['+', '+', '+']]]
```

I know this behavior from code like `f = [[['+'] * 3] * 3] * 3` and thought I could prevent it with `copy.copy()`, but this obviously doesn't work. I tried this with Python 3.2.2 on android (QPython 3) and with Python 2.7 on Windows, I got the same results. Please note that I *don't* want to use a non-standard library like numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the copy.deepcopy(). the copy.copy() is just shallowcopy.

the difference between these two methods:

> the difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy arrays for this giving more convenient slicing and indexing operations. Also allows for more dimensions than 2-3 and cleaner code.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.empty((width, height), dtype=object)
```

Then you can fill it via your desired method, e.g:

```
import itertools
for x, y in itertools.product(range(width), range(height)):
     X[x, y] = '+'
```